# Destiny DLC 2 not carrying over to Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, destiny, xbox-one

I bought the 1st DLC expansion on Xbox 360 and when I got Destiny for Xbox One it carried over. But when I got DLC 2 on Xbox One it didn't carry over to Xbox 360. Does anyone know how to get expansions from Xbox one to Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can't transfer DLC from one system to another. You'd have to purchase it for both consoles.

In Destiny's case, there was a 'Last Gen to Next Gen' [upgrade program](http://attackofthefanboy.com/news/destiny-dlc-will-transfer-last-gen-next-gen/) for select  DLC, but only for a limited time. You probably qualified for this when you bought the first expansion. But it expired on January 15, 2015.

(This is assuming you purchased the DLC individually, instead of in the season pass.)

So unfortunately, if you want the DLC on the 360, you'll have to buy it on the 360.

However, if you purchased the season pass on the 360, then you should try  navigating to the DLC page on the Xbox 360 store and see if it is unlocked and just needs to be downloaded.

Comment: Also, next gen upgrade does not allow downgrading back to Xbox 360

Answer (score 0):

If you buy on Xbox 360 it will carry over to Xbox one. If you do it backwards it won't work (I agree it's the stupidest thing ever). It says so when you buy the expansion on the 360, that it will work on one but not vise-versa. Call Xbox for a refund and then repurchase on the 360.

Comment: Based on the other, older, answer this probably won't work - "last gen to next gen upgrade program for select DLC, but only for a limited time[...] expired on January 15, 2015".